# Python's gettext locale default

Tags: python, linux, gettext

I write in British English en_GB. The script works fine for a language I have supplied a .mo translation file for. However if I run it on my computer there is no need for a .mo file to translate from en_GB to en_GB and there isn't one, so the `gettext.translation` fails. Is there a way I could avoid this? (The same would happen on a computer which is setup for any other language I hadn't made a file for.)

```
import locale
language = locale.getlocale()[0]
lang = gettext.translation("myapp", localedir='blah', languages=[language])
_ = lang.gettext

print(_('message'))
```

A work-around would be to have an en_GB to en_GB file, but that is a bodge and would be extra maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `fallback` to `True`.

```
lang = gettext.translation("myapp", localedir='blah', languages=[language], fallback=True)
```

This will make `gettext.translation` return a [`NullTranslations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations) instance, instead of throwing an `OSError` exception.

`NullTranslations`'s `gettext` method will just return the supplied message back.